# NegativeArraySizeException while unzipping a ZipInputStream

Tags: java, file, exception, client-server

I try to send some files from server to client using ZipInputStream/ZipOutputStream.

in server, everythng goes well, but in client, when I wanna unzip it, the size of the file is **-1**

so it fails. what should I do and why it happens?

```
             socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",3000);

         String outDir = "C:\\here";



             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());            



            ZipInputStream zips = new ZipInputStream(bis);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = null;




              while(null != (zipEntry = zips.getNextEntry())){
             String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
                File outFile = new File(outDir + "/" + fileName);
        System.out.println(outFile.getName()+"      "+zipEntry.getCompressedSize());

    if(zipEntry.isDirectory()){
    File zipEntryFolder = new File(zipEntry.getName());
    if(zipEntryFolder.exists() == false){
     outFile.mkdirs();

    }

        continue;
    }else{
    File parentFolder = outFile.getParentFile();
    if(parentFolder.exists() == false){
     parentFolder.mkdirs();
    }
   }

   System.out.println("ZipEntry::"+zipEntry.getCompressedSize());



        FileWriter fW=new FileWriter(outFile);
            try (BufferedWriter bfW = new BufferedWriter(fW)) {
                bfW.write(zips.getNextEntry().toString());
            }
                                                                    }

              socket.close();

                                                            }
```

the result for *zipEntry.getCompressedSize();* is equal to -1. but right after writing it into socket in server, i check the size and it is the actual size. so I feel puzzled.

the exception that IDE gives is **Error in Client invalid stored block lengths**

Comment: @JqueryLearner why null? it's already filled with nextentry if you read the code carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can't ever rely on `getSize` returning the actual uncompressed size. You need to call `zips.read` from the ZipInputStream until it doesn't read any more bytes.

Comment: now i put the whole code, including thw whole process, it gives an error. i know if narrowing from _Long_ into _int_ it may cause change of sign, but at the line  i already mentioned, i didnt do any casting, but still gives **-1**

Comment: It will always return -1. You cannot rely on it returning the size. It returns the size some of the time, but most of the time it returns -1. The documentation even says so. (well, it doesn't say it happens most of the time, but it does say it happens)

Comment: what about _zipEntry.getCompressedSize();_? because it also gives **-1** and the IDE gives this as an exception _Error in Client invalid stored block lengths_

Comment: I don't know about getCompressedSize, but I thought you wanted the uncompressed size.

Comment: but first before uncompressing, i tried to see the size, because of the exception the IDE gives, which is _Error in Client invalid stored block lengths_

Comment: i also updated my code, u may look at it and tell me if anything wrong there?